# Incorrect filepath from os module

Tags: python, raspberry-pi

I'm using a Raspberry Pi 4 to do some AI recognition. In the folder, I put some images for my code to recognize(the code and images were perfectly fine before trasnferring it onto my Raspberry Pi). When running it on the Raspberry Pi, it produces the wrong filepath:

result: `/home/pi0/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/lightimg_1.jpg` 
expected: `/home/pi0/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/light/img_1.jpg`

The same thing happens no matter how many folders I put in the path. It's still missing that last forward slash in the file line.

My code:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    path = os.path.abspath('..') + '//light//'
    for f in os.listdir():
        if f.endswith('.jpg') or f.endswith('.JPG') or f.endswith('.png') or f.endswith('.PNG'):
            print(f)
            detect(path, f)
```

Is there anything to fix, or is this just a Raspberry Pi problem?

Comment: Can you try replacing `path = os.path.abspath('..') + '//light//' `  with  `path = os.path.abspath('..') + '/light/' `

Comment: You should (also) join paths using [`os.path.join()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.join) *not* using string concatenation.

Comment: @Solen'ya tried it, same result

Comment: @martineau also tried your solution, it seems like raspberry pi is removing the last forward slash for all files, and when that happens, even using os.path.join(), the forward slash in the path doesn't get added back correctlly.

Comment: `os.listdir()` is returning a list of the files in the current working directory. You're only assigning a value to `path` once, outside the `for` loop. Inside the loop it never changes. I have no idea what `detect()` does, but `path` and `f` have nothing to do with one another.

Comment: `Path(__file__).parent / "light"`

Comment: @martineau `detect()` is the recognition of the image. It takes in a path (path), and an image(f). From what I know about OS, that one path would work fine, with the image path just being added to the back of it.

Comment: @drum's snippet of code is the `pathlib.Path` equivalent of `path = os.path.abspath('../light')`. Anyway why would you be passing `detect` the path to the `light` subdirectory and the file names found in the current working directory (which is — very likely — not the same directory)?

Comment: @martineau 1) tried removing the folder, same result. 2) i made sure the working directory was in the /light folder. Raspberry pi just seems to be removing the last / or something(and os doesn't add it back)